# How do I find a item in ListView control?

Tags: c, winapi, listview, ipc

My list view contains 3 columns Name, address and phone number.

I want to retrieve an index for a particular name.

I'm using `ListView_FindItem` macro to find the index number but when my code comes to this line it crashes the program.

It just says Payroll has stopped working. Windows can check online  for a solution to the problem.

I'm sure I have passed right handle to the `ListView_FindItem` macro but I'm not sure about the `LVFINDINFO` structure.

Here's my code

```
WCHAR szProcess[80] = {0};
LVFINDINFO item = {LVFI_STRING, (LPCTSTR) szProcess};

//code to find parent handles
...

//code to find index
index = ListView_FindItem(hwndListView, -1, &item);
```

I'm not sure about the `LVFI_STRING` flag and I have even tried passing a constant `LVFINDINFO` structure to `ListView_FindItem` macro still my program crashes.

> Note : The above code is not part of
>   the payroll application. I mean to say
>   the payroll application has the
>   listview and I'm trying to search the
>   item from other application.

Can some one point me in a right direction ?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot cast string types.  Post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @Hans Passant How do I find stack trace? I don't have Visual Studio with me. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Trying to debug code without a debugger is rather pointless.  Why do you even try?

Comment: @Hans Passant I just have Windows SDK with me. I'll post the stack trace once I reach my college.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is a little unclear, but I interpret it that you are sending `LVM_FINDITEM` message (via the `ListView_FindItem()` macro) to a window in a different process.

This simply does not work for this particular Windows message since it passes a pointer to a struct in the calling process which is meaningless when interpreted in the context of the other process (the payroll app that owns the list view).

To solve your problem you could allocate memory in the other process although this is quite a complex task.  A commonly cited example of the technique is to be found in the Code Project article, [Stealing Program's Memory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/int64_memsteal.aspx).

Perhaps a simpler approach would be to use WM_COPYDATA which will marshal string data between processes.  If that doesn't have enough flexibility then you'd need to find another IPC mechanism, e.g. named pipes.

Comment: @Searock, did it work? I tried the CodeProject method to get the titles of column headers from another process and it worked nicely. What I am confused about is that calling `GetWindowText()` works the same way: you pass a pointer to a buffer to put the string it, but that **does** work for windows from another process. `:-?`

Comment: @Synetech Yes it worked. I'm not sure why [GetWindowText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) is not working for you. You can get window text of other process too. Perhaps if you could show me your code, may be I can help.

Comment: @Searock, `GetWindowText()` **does** work; that’s what’s confusing. It requires a buffer just like `FindItem` and `GetColumn` do, but while the list-control functions don’t work for another process, `GetWindowText` *does*. That makes no sense.

Comment: @Synetech Yeah you are right, Its confusing. I'll inform you if I find an answer on this.

Comment: @Searock, thanks, but don’t worry about it; Raymond Chen [answered it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526772/).