# Passing a pointer to a local variable to another process works sometimes and not others

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, ipc

A while back I wrote a program that lets you pick and modify windows. It uses `WindowFromPoint()` to get a handle to the window under the mouse cursor and calls `GetWindowText()` on that to get the window’s title. This works just fine.

I then added the ability to get the title of columns of a list-control. The problem is that unlike `GetColumnWidth()` which returns the width, there is no corresponding function to get the title. Instead, getting the title of the column header requires passing a buffer to `GetColumn()` to fill with the title. As such, when I assign the `pszText` member of an `LVCOLUMN` structure to a pointer to a buffer and pass the struct to `GetColumn()`, the other process interprets the pointer as within its own memory space. Obviously this won’t work.

I worked around that by using a method from a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/int64_memsteal.aspx). It worked great. However I am still confused about why `GetWindowText()` *did* work.

It is confusing because `GetWindowText()` works the same as `GetColumn()`; it does not return the window title, it takes a buffer/variable to put the title in.

So why does passing a variable to another process to be filled work in one scenario but not another?

Here is a snippet that gets the window title:

```
// m_Wnd is a pointer to a window class, pointing to a window in another process
CWnd *m_Wnd=WindowFromPoint(point);

// t is a local variable within this program’s address space
CString t;

// passing a reference to a local variable to another process
m_Wnd->GetWindowText(t); //works correctly!
```

Here is a corresponding snippet to get the title of a column:

```
// *lc points to a list-control in another process
int         colwidth = lc->GetColumnWidth(col); //works correctly!

// local variables
CString     colname  = _T("");
LVCOLUMN    col;
memset(&col, 0, sizeof(col));

col.mask=LVCF_TEXT;
col.cchTextMax=256;
col.pszText=colname.GetBuffer(256);  // passing a pointer to local buffer
BOOL ret=lc.GetColumn(colnum, &col); // buffer is empty
colname.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Comment: Possibly similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688927/how-do-i-find-a-item-in-listview-control

Comment: @luskan, thank you! I used the method from CodeProject and it worked. I’m still wondering why `GetWindowText()` works, so I’ll re-write the question a bit to focus on that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetWindowText` is special. When you call it on a window that belongs to another process, [it doesn't actually call the other process to get the text](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx).

`CListCtrl::GetColumn` on the other hand is an inline function (see `afxcmn.inl`) that calls `SendMessage`, so the message goes to the other process, which then interprets the pointer in its own memory space.

Comment: Nice; cognitive dissonance resolved. whew! Thanks Raymond. I actually tried replacing my call to `GetWindowText()` with a call to `SendMessage(WM_GETTEXT)` and it still worked. I guess that’s where this line comes in: *Note also that since WM_GETTEXT is in the system message range (0 to WM_USER-1), you do not need to do any parameter marshalling (and in fact, you shouldn't). USER will do the marshalling for you.*

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a suggestion... Could be that the other window is Unicode.  In that case, you might have to use the wice character versions to get it to work.  There is an API function IsWindowUnicode() which will tell you whether a given window is native Unicode.

Comment: The buffer is large enough to handle it, and the `CString` object and `_T()` macro (MFC version of the `TEXT()`) already handle character width.